# How to perform this string concatenation?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a list:

```
list1 = ['test', 'motor', 'mobile']
```

I want to create another list using items from list1 as `key` and `vid[key]` as value, like to output below:

```
list2=[
'test':  vid['test'],
'motor': vid['motor'],
'mobile':vid['mobile']]
```

Comment: What is vid?  Is it a dictionary, containing 1 entry? (i.e. you want to create a list of dictionaries where the key in each dictionary is 'vid' and the value is one of the three strings?

Comment: vid is a string, can be any string like: `'test':car['test']`  I can have the whole dic as string but with that pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I understand what you are trying to do is accept a list of strings containing individual words and for each word produce a line of output of the form "'word' = vid['word']".

To accomplish this:

```
for wrd in list1:
    print(f"'{wrd}' = vid['{wrd}']")
```

Which produces:

```
'test' = vid['test']
'motor' = vid['motor']
'mobile' = vid['mobile']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list2 = {}
for key in list:
    list2[key] = vid[key]
```

Comment: vid is not defined.

Comment: well yes, obviously since you use vid in your example but dont define it, I assumed you would provide it